# Established conventions for distinguishing the consequence relations of FOL

Tags: logic, notation, soft-question, terminology, first-order-logic

**Are there any established conventions for distinguishing the consequence relations of first-order logic? I'm thinking both in terms of what to call them (e.g. global vs local) and what notation to use.**

---

What follows is background and motivation for the question and some links to answers on this site or external resources.

---

For example, is it at least somewhat conventional to use $\Gamma \models \varphi$ for the local consequence relation and $\Gamma \Rightarrow \varphi$ or $\varphi \mathop{=\!\!\!|} \Gamma$ or $\Gamma \models^g \varphi$ or something for the global one? For example, [this answer by sequitur](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226163) to a similar question I had about modal logic uses $\models^g$.

As for my motivation, I'm trying to (re)-learn first-order logic thoroughly so I can a) prove stuff about various proof calculi and b) understand my model theory textbooks better.

---

Also, is having a logic with multiple consequence relations so awkward/weird that it's better to talk about *two distinct first-order logics* rather than one with multiple consequence relations. For example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3363916) (among others that I've seen before but can't find) defines a logic as a set of sentences and *exactly one* consequence relation. I know there's another answer out there that defines what a logic is in general more explicitly. I'll update the link when I find it.

Also, it is possible to define stranger consequence relations for FOL that permit, for example, adding new free variables (via $\forall x \mathop. \varphi \models \varphi(x)$) but not removing them or permit removing free variables but not adding them. I'm assuming that these consequence relations (and possibly others?) are not really worth talking about. *Is this assumption correct?*

---

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695520/which-fol-consequence-relation-is-better-to-teach), which cites [this email](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2004-September/008483.html), discusses which consequence relation for first-order logic is better to teach students. I'll call them $\models^g$ for the *global* consequence relation that ranges over variable assignments and $\models^l$ for the *local* one that doesn't.

First, let $M \models \varphi$ hold if and only if $M, v \models \varphi$ for all $M$-valuations on the free variables of $\varphi$ $v$.

Let $M, v \models \varphi$, where $v$ is a valuation that is constrained to only assign interpretations to the free variables of $\varphi$.

I'm being pedantic about the free variables of the valuation so that $\lnot (x = x)$ is a tautology when the structure is empty, but $\lnot \forall x \mathop. x = x$ and $\lnot \forall x \mathop. x \neq x$ are both non-tautologies because they don't have any free variables. Previously, I liked to define $v$ to assign an interpretation to every possible variable symbol, but this has the unfortunate consequence of making everything a tautology in empty structures (and I think it also makes $\forall$-elimination work in a weird symmetry-breaking way).

The *local relation* is defined as follows.

$ \Gamma \models \varphi$ if and only if for all models $M$ and $M$-valuations on $\text{FV}(\varphi)$ $v$, if $M, v \models \Gamma$ then $M, v \models \varphi$.

The *global relation* is defined as follows.

$ \Gamma \models \varphi$ if and only if for all models $M$, if $M \models \Gamma$  then $M \models \varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the most common convention in first-order logic is that the consequence relation $\models$ is something that only applies to theories and sentences. That is, it just doesn't make sense to write $\Gamma\models \varphi$ when $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ have free variables. And in the absence of free variables, there is no difference between your "local" and "global" consequence relations.

But I agree that sometimes it is useful to talk about the consequence relation between (sets of) formulas with free variables. For example, when proving soundness for certain proof systems (e.g. in a sequent calculus $\varphi\vdash \psi$ makes sense when $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have free variables, and we want it to imply $\varphi\models \psi$). Or in model theory, when thinking about notions like isolated types, it can be more convenient to write $T\cup  \varphi(x)\models p(x)$ instead of $T\models \forall  x\,(\varphi(x)\rightarrow \psi(x))$  for all $\psi(x)\in p(x)$.

In these situations, as you might already guess from the examples I used, I think there's only one reasonable meaning of $\models$: what you call the "local relation". I don't think I've ever encountered the "global relation".

More precisely, I would say that first-order logic has infinitely many consequence relations, one denoted $\models_x$ for each variable context $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$. For the expression $\varphi\models_{x} \psi$ to be well-formed, the free variables in $\varphi$ and $\psi$ must all come from the context $x$. And $\varphi\models_{x} \psi$ means that for all structures $M$ and all tuples $a = (a_1,\dots,a_n)\in M^x$, if $M\models \varphi(a)$, then $M\models \psi(a)$. Note that this is equivalent to saying that for all structures $M$, the definable set $\varphi(M) = \{a\in M^x\mid M\models \varphi(a)\}$ is a subset of $\psi(M) = \{a\in M^x\mid M\models \psi(a)\}$.  The notation can be extended naturally to sets of formulas, so $p(x)\models q(x)$ expresses a containment of type-definable sets across all models.

Most of the time, people will suppress the variable context subscript, just writing $\varphi(x) \models \psi(x)$, and think of this as a single consequence relation. This is safe to do in the classical semantics with no empty structures. But if you allow empty structures or multi-sorted structures with empty sorts, then it's an important technicality to notice that the consequence relations in distinct variable contexts are distinct. For example, writing $()$ for the empty variable context, we have $\forall x\, \bot\not\models_{()} \exists x\,\top$, since an empty structure validates $\forall x\, \bot$ but not $\exists x\, \top$. But on the other hand, $\forall x\, \bot\models_y \exists x\, \top$, vacuously, since $\forall x\,\bot$ is only true in an empty structure, and an empty structure admits no interepretations of the variable $y$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695520/which-fol-consequence-relation-is-better-to-teach) says that the global relation appears in Mendelson et al. I'm not sure how popular that book is or if it's the most popular one that uses the global relation. I like the family of relations per variable context $\models_{\vec{x}}$. Is it capable of assessing the truth of $\varphi \models_{\vec{x}} \psi$ when $\text{FV}(\varphi)$ and $\text{FV}(\psi)$ are not equal to $\vec{x}$? Do you know if there's a book or similar that uses the $\models_\vec{x}$ approach? Thank you.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in Mendelson that I disagree with. But I just had a look in my copy (6th edition), and it seems to me that he uses the local relation. On p. 62, he writes "$C$ is said to be a logical consequence of a set of wfs $\Gamma$ if and only if, in every interpretation, every sequence that satisfies every wf in $\Gamma$ also satisfies $C$". That's the local relation, right? @GregoryNisbet

Comment: When you say $\mathrm{FV}(\varphi)$ is not equal to $\vec{x}$, do you just mean that not every variable in $\vec{x}$ appears in $\varphi$? If so, then yes: you can always view a formula as a formula in any larger variable context.

Comment: Interesting. I don't actually have a copy of Mendelson. The person who asked the question I linked to does and the generalization rule they cite $A(x) \vdash \forall x \mathop. A(x)$ is consistent with the global one and not consistent with the local one. The quote from page 62 is the local relation if "interpretation" refers to the pair $(M, v)$ ... if interpretation just refers to $M$, though, then I think it's the global one. I think interpretation probably refers to $(M, v)$ though.

Comment: Also, thanks, that's another thing I was mistaken about. I thought $\vec{x}$ had to match $\text{FV}(\varphi)$ exactly so that tautologies in empty structures would be handled correctly, but I get the behavior I want if I merely insist that $\text{FV}(\varphi) \subset \vec{x}$.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I think "interpretation" refers to $M$ and "sequence" refers to $v$.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet For more on what's going on in Mendelson: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576172/7062. Unfortunately I don't have a reference for you to a book that uses the $\models_x$ approach. I'm not aware of any introductory logic books that (in my view) get all their conventions right. Maybe I'll write one someday...