# What is the modern convention for these model theory defintions?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I've seen different definitions and am wondering what is the modern convention.

### '$\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(x)$'

Def. 1: $\mathcal{M}$ thinks $\phi(x)$ is true on *some* interpretation.

Def. 2: $\mathcal{M}$ thinks $\phi(x)$ is true on *all* interpretations.

### '$\phi(x)\vDash\psi(x)$'

Def. 1: For every structure $\mathcal{M}$ and every interpretation $s$, if $\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(x)[s]$, then $\mathcal{M}\vDash\psi(x)[s]$.

Def. 2: The same as $\forall x\phi(x)\vDash\forall x\psi(x)$ i.e. the formulas are understood as their universal closures.

Comment: In my experience the answer in each case is "Definition 1" - *usually*. But note that this leads to a break with an earlier equivalence: we no longer have $$\varphi(x)\models\psi(x)\quad\iff\quad [\forall\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{M}\models\varphi(x)\iff\mathcal{M}\models\psi(x))].$$ For this reason I personally try to avoid both notations.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am not sure why someone would want that equivalence. It doesn't make intuitive sense since the left hand side is a conditional, but the right hand side is a biconditional.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo: the right-hand-side $\iff$ should have been an $\implies$.

Comment: For Question 2, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4347370/7062). For Question 1, I agree with everyone else here that the notation $M\models \varphi(x)$, when $\varphi(x)$ has free variables, should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 4):

### '$\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(x)$'

This is rarely used and myself I'd recommend **not** to use it.
I would interpret it as $\mathcal{M}⊧ ∀x \phi(x)$.

### '$\phi(x)\vDash\psi(x)$'

This is used more frequently (also as $\phi(x)\vdash\psi(x)$). It means that $\mathcal{M}\vDash∀x[\phi(x)\rightarrow\psi(x)$ for every $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Isn't it used all the time in model theory for talking about types? A set of formulas $p(x)$ is a partial type if there is a model $\mathcal{M}\vDash T\cup p(x)$.

Comment: I agree. The second one is very common, although mostly with $\vdash$ rather than $\models$ (also with types, not just formulas), while the first one, while technically correct, is awkward, not that useful, and (in conjuction with the other one), simply confusing.

Comment: @T-Biconditional: That is incorrect. $p(x)$ is a partial type if there is an $M\models T\cup \exists x p(x)$.